# How to combine connector in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I hacve problem with connector in draw io
[image]
[image]

And how to combine connector like that?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the moment draw.io doesn't support edge to edge connection but feel free to vote for it here: https://trello.com/c/cq7QoWjS/313-edge-to-edge-connections

As a workaround, you could add very small e.g. dot on one edge and use it for connecting.

Regards,

Comment: Thank u for your info @Marija

Comment: This is now on Github and declined: https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/1617

Answer (score 4):

Use Waypoints.

1. Double-click and select the small dot which represents a so-called Waypoint.
2. Then draw 3 lines from that way point

   - One down to the box
   - One to the right to the oval shape
   - One up
     [image]
3. If you don't like the small dot to be visible, then select it and untick `Line`
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

Just uncheck the "Grid" view:

[image]